# Fetches failing on site deployed on netlify- status 500, cors error, uncaught (in promise) syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redux, netlify

Have my backend of my site deployed to heroku and my frontend deployed to netlify. I can login, signup and logout on my site when running on netlify, but other functionality and fetches are not working. Also should note that everything on my site was working perfectly before I had started deploying.

I am seeing these errors in the console: [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
photo-sharer-kkirby16.netlify.app/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at allPosts.js:19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXkPA.png)

I console logged what the response is in my get request fetch that should get all the posts (instagram-esque app) and it showed as this in the console:

[This picture shows there is a status 500 cors error and more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWHef.png)

Here is how I have my getAllPosts action creator set up, which is not working to fetch to get all the posts for some reason.

```
export const getAllPosts = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch("https://photo-sharer-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1/posts", {
      credentials: "include",
      //say "credentials: include" for when you need to send an authenticated or authorized request of some sort.
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(setAllPosts(response));
      });
  };
};
```

Here is my cors.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "https://photo-sharer-kkirby16.netlify.app"

    resource "*",
             headers: :any,
             methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
             credentials: true
  end
end
```

First time trying to deploy a site and would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Rails version ?

Comment: @ImranAhmad Hey there, it is Rails 6.0.4.1